# Azure storage containers and routing from wildcard root domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

I have a storage account in Azure with a container named clients. Inside the container I have folders for various clients, i.e:

```
mysite.blob.core.windows.net/clients/one
mysite.blob.core.windows.net/clients/two
```

I also have my own site set up as a static website, i.e:

```
mysite.z33.web.core.windows.net
```

On top of that, I have a custom domain: `mysite.com`. Is it possible, using Azure CDN or Azure Front Door/Application Gateway to route traffic like so (in a way that doesn't require further configuration per client):

`one.mysite.com` -> `mysite.blob.core.windows.net/clients/one`

`two.mysite.com` -> `mysite.blob.core.windows.net/clients/two`

`mysite.com` -> `mysite.z33.web.core.windows.net`

So far I have tried doing this with Azure CDN but I don't think it's possible, it has a rules engine that seems quite flexible but I don't think they support wildcard domains, unless I'm (hopefully) wrong. Ideally I'd like it to be done in some sort of wildcard way, so that is maps:

`<client>.mysite.com` -> `mysite.blob.core.windows.net/clients/<client>`

I don't really want to have to add more rules or configuration every time I have a new client.

Comment: Any update? Is my reply helpful to you?

Comment: Hi, your reply is helpful but unfortunately it doesn't get exactly what I was hoping for - a hands off way of routing wildcard domains to buckets using some sort of rules within azure. I've changed my approach to this problem, sorry for not responding sooner.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you could use an **alias** record to add a root domain as the `custom domains` in your CDN endpoints if you use Azure CDN to host your DNS zone. In this case, you need to set up multiple endpoints for each custom domain. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#create-a-cname-dns-record) for more details. But Pointing a zone apex to CDN endpoints for **Azure CDN from Akamai** is currently not supported. You can use other CDN price tier.

If you use the Azure application gateway, you may configure [multiple sites listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-multiple-sites-portal) to receive different incoming host traffic and use [path-based URL rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal) to route the traffic to the backends. It looks like a complex configuration and hard to troubleshoot the app gw related issue.

The azure front door should also do this trick, it supports [onboard a root domain on your Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain) also allows [wildcard domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-wildcard-domain). The route path is also easy to configure. See [path matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching#path-matching) for more details.

Hope this information could help you.